# Exluding JBoss AS 7.1.1 webservices subsystem

Tags: web-services, jboss7.x

I'm trying to exclude the **webservices** subsystem in my jboss AS 7.1.1 by adding a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file, which looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="webservices" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

In Eclipse, I get an error in the aforementioned file which marks "deployment" as an invalid element. If I disregard the error and run my project, I get the following error:

```
19:40:15,531 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."CXF.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."CXF.war".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "CXF.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Error loading jboss-structure.xml from C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\CXF.war\WEB-INF\jboss-deployment-structure.xml
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:277) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:249) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.deploy(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:134) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2}jboss-deployment-structure'
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:271) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on the answer from this URL:
[How can I use Apache CXF 2.6.7 as dependency of my war project and not CXF that is installed in the modules of JBoss 7.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714655/how-can-i-use-apache-cxf-2-6-7-as-dependency-of-my-war-project-and-not-cxf-that)

> Just a note, exclude-subsystems functionality and
>   deployment-strucure:1.2 was added in 7.1.2 and as such will not work
>   on on 7.1.1.

I'm using JBoss AS 7.1.1, so this explains it.

Comment: did you find any solution for v7.1.1?

Answer (score 1):

- From the following error i can see that the structure of war file deployed is incorrect, so you can change it to a correct format and then try...

  ```
  19:40:15,531 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."CXF.war".STRUCTURE:
  ```
- From the following error - urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2 named subsystem is not present(i think it may be - urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1) and it is also showing the "parser error" so check the xml file also :

  ```
  Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1]
  Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2}jboss-deployment-structure'
  ```
- A simple war file structure for reference as follows  :

  ```
  Demo.war
  |
  |---- META-INF  
  |           |----jboss-deployment-structure.xml
  |           |----MANIFEST.MF
  |          
  |---- WEB-INF 
  |           |---- classes
  |           |   
  |           |---- lib
  |           |      
  |           |---- web.xml
  |
  |---- index.jsp
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
/web-app_3_0.xsd"
metadata-complete="false">
```

If you want to migrate from weblogic to JBoss, just change the schema as above.
It will works.